# I'm asking about how to make a math expression from (ambigous) phrase. Is this off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

This is my question: [“3 times a is increased by b” vs “3 times a increased by b”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204821/3-times-a-is-increased-by-b-vs-3-times-a-increased-by-b?noredirect=1#comment433480_204821)

As I stated in [a comment to SrJoven](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204821/3-times-a-is-increased-by-b-vs-3-times-a-increased-by-b?noredirect=1#comment433425_204821), this question is not about how to read (or speak) a mathematical expression, it is how to interpret a phrase to a mathematical expression. However SrJoven and FumbleFingers think that this is off-topic and it should be in Mathematics.SE. What do you think?

Comment: I've already expressed my reasons and haven't seen any particular indication of exactly why the question is for English Language and Usage. If Mathematics threw it back here, I'd take that as a "why" ... but then again, a math question that evaluates to a math expression seems exactly what math forums do.

Comment: It sounds like a duplicate of the "ten times"question to me.

Comment: @KitFox: do you mean this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56350/is-the-word-tenfold-a-misnomer)? This question is about definition, not grammar as mine.

Comment: Why do you think your 3 times question is about grammar? I asked you this, and you said It was not about the grammar of the question, but the mathematical interpretation of the question's text. Which is math(s).

Comment: Arrg, let me try to understand the problem again. The question I get is on the GRE test, so I don't think that this should belong to ELL, because the aim of the test is testing the abilities of native speakers. The grammar of the test is well written, but it leads to ambiguous, for which I am asking right now. Once I get the correct meaning of the test, I will be able to form the correct mathematical expression easily. Math is not my question, English in math is my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what English grammar speakers think. There is only one correct answer on an exam, and in this case, the answer is definable by BODMAS/PEMDAS as it's read, regardless of your interpretation (or that of alleged English experts). The GRE answer is a math(s) answer. The question: "Is this ambiguous?" Was never asked. And, thus far, never asked in the one place you should get a definitive, final, answer. It's not even "what do native English speakers think." It's about what is the answer given the question. And there's only one correct answer.

Comment: Ahh, I get your point. This is a subtle case @.@